# Apache not working in XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

All correct nothing changed in ini files, but **XAMPP** not working and showing something JAVA(refer to screenshot). This may be a case of JAVA package update but really im not sure if I did this. How could i try to figure out the error as nothing seems to be in error log files as well.[image]

I already searched a lot before asking :)

Comment: Tried SCM as well but no apache service to start/stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Skype ? Skype automatically blocks the port 80

Stop Skype - Try

If apache Works - change skype settings

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that your port80 is occupied with something else. Try quitting **skype** if you have one or try localhost in your browser and see if port 80 is free(i.e. it should open xampp).

Alternatively you can use **cport** to see if port 80 is free.